# Fill an array with unique random integers

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to fill a small array with unique values from a bigger array. How do I check the uniqueness?

Here's what I have:

```
int[] numbers45 = new int[45];

for (int i = 0; i <= 44; i++)             // I create a big array
{
    numbers45[i] = i + 1;                
}         

Random r = new Random();
int[] draw5 = new int[5];                 //new small array 

Console.WriteLine("The 5 draws are:");

for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    draw5[i] = numbers45[r.Next(numbers45.Length)];  //I fill the small array with values from the big one. BUT the values might not be unique.
    Console.WriteLine(draw5[i]);
}
```

Comment: You can either have separate table to track drawn values and draw until you have only unique values, or you can remove values that you already have drawn  and then draw from numbers45.Length - i.

Comment: I would use a Yates shuffle on the large array

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do what you are asking.

*First off, though, I would recommend to use one of the classes which wraps the array type and adds some extra functionality you could use (in this case a `List` would probably be a perfect structure to use)!*

One way to handle this is to check if the value is already in the `draw5` array. This can be done with (for example) the `List<T>.Contains(T)` function, and if it exists, try another.

Personally though, I would probably have randomized the first array with the `OrderBy` linq method and just return a random number, like:

```
numbers45.OrderBy(o => random.Next());
```

That way the numbers are already random and unique when it is supposed to be added to the second list.

And a side note: Remember that arrays indexes starts on index `0`. In your second loop, you start at 1 and go to 4, that is, you wont set a value to the first index.
You could just run `for (int i=0;i<5;i++)` to get it right.

Comment: random.Next() is not optimal as as a tie retains prior order

Comment: Aye, just used that as an example, hehe.

Answer (score -1):

```
HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>();
int next = random.next(45);
while(hs.Length <=5)
{
    if(!hs.Contains(array[next]))
        hs.Add(array[next]);
    next = random next(45);
}
```

Comment: FYI: [Somebody flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18253855) your answer and it went into the Low Quality Posts queue - presumably because your answer is just code without accompanying text to explain.

Comment: a) Does this code compile? b) What does `!hs.Contains(array[next])` achieve? Could it be removed?

Comment: [*When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/1364007) - directed at the flagger, not mjwills

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by [Jite's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47812157/6577199), I changed to use `Guid` to randomize the numbers

```
var randomized = numbers45.OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

Then you could take the draws by:

```
var draws = randomized.Take(5).ToArray;
```